# Error: read ECONNRESET while connecting to azure sql

Tags: mysql, node.js, azure

I've created and tested MySql scripts it works fine on localhost but when I try to connect to azure I get the following errors:

```
var mysql = require("mysql");
const fs = require('fs');

var config = {
    host: 'myhost',
    database: 'mydb',
    user: 'myusername',
    password: 'mypass',
    port: 1433, 
    ssl: {
        rejectUnauthorized: true,
        ca: fs.readFileSync("my path to ssl")
    }
}

function initializeConnection(config) {
    function addDisconnectHandler(connection) {
        connection.on("error", function (error) {
            if (error instanceof Error) {
                if (error.code === "PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST") {
                    console.error(error.stack);
                    console.log("Lost connection. Reconnecting..."); 

                    initializeConnection(connection.config);
                } else if (error.fatal) {  
                    error; 
                }
            }
        });
    }

    var connection = mysql.createConnection(config); 

    addDisconnectHandler(connection);

    connection.connect(
        function (err) { 
        if (err) { 
            console.log("!!! Cannot connect !!! Error:");
            throw err;
        }
        else
        {
           console.log("Connection established.");
        }
    }); 
    return connection;
}

var connection = initializeConnection(config);

module.exports.connection = connection;
```

But I get this error

```
errno: -4077,
code: 'ECONNRESET',
syscall: 'read',
fatal: true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the error because i mistook Azure SQL database connection implementation for Azure MySQL database connection, didn't knew that both where complete different service.

For clarification:
To connect to Azure SQL I have to use Tedious, follow the instruction [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/connect-query-nodejs?tabs=windows)

but for Azure MySQL use [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/connect-nodejs).